# is there a real-life example to elaborate NP-complete?

Tags: np-complete

In computational complexity theory, a problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) when it can be solved by a restricted class of brute force search algorithms and it can be used to simulate any other problem with a similar algorithm.

is there a real-life example to elaborate NP-complete? like tossing coins to elaborate Bernoulli distribution ?

Comment: Travelling salesman is a classic

Comment: @JackCrawford thanks for your comments, does "salesman" mean "t = n!" or "$t = 2^n$"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are plenty. There are two that I am more familiar with. For one, consider graph coloring where you want to color a connected graph such that no two touching vertices have the same color. Or perhaps longest path problem, where one seeks to find the longest simple path by the number of edges, or weights. There should be several others mentioned in pages such as Wikipedia.

In addition, another simple game that uses NP complete is that block game where you tap on a block and it removes all the "adjacent" blocks of the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Cliques of a graph are connected subgraphs. Clique cover attempts to split the graph into as few sub-cliques as possible, and that reduces to an NP-complete process as well.

Answer (score 0):

Battleship is an NP complete game when done by computer.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would please provide a little bit more detail?